# Magento 1.9 - Replace template files by store ID

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

Let's say i want to use different template files on storeID 3.

The modules frontend folder is: checkout

If the storeID is equal to 3 I want Magento to use customcheckout instead.

Is there a way of achieving this, without rewriting or copying the whole module from app/code and renaming all the things?

I have been looking at layout handles and i got it to render both layouts, yet i could not remove the original "checkout" files.

Comment: You could possibly unset the block you want to change and reset it before the page is rendered

Comment: How would you recommend to do it? 

With a observer?

Comment: yes would be best way to do that id recommend controller_action_layout_load_before

Comment: How would you unset the current layout and reset the new one? 

I had success with: 

$update = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate();
$update->addHandle('mycustomhadnle_danish');

How would you unset the 'checkout_handle'?

Comment: please read https://webkul.com/blog/ways-to-create-unset-blocks-in-magento/ as a reference to setting and unsetting blocks

Comment: Thats for magento 2. I was looking for a more "steamlined" solution rather than unsetting / resetting all the template/child blocks :D 

Thanks for the options and insight.

Comment: A lot of the function names for magento 1 and magento 2 are still the same i have used that maily for reference on function names and implimentation techniques